# Mailer Broken from Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

So I've written a mailer entitled UserMailer containing a method entitled test.  The method accepts two parameters: `user` (object) and `recipient` (email).

From the console I can send the mailer with the command
`UserMailer::deliver_test(User.find(1), 'email@email.com')` and the email sends successfully.

But if I define a the same command or its counterpart `UserMailer.test(User.find(1), 'email@email.com').deliver` in `users#mail`, accessing the action via users/mail returns nothing.

What do I have to do for the controller to trigger delivery properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the mailer's class method from inside your controller

```
UserMailer.deliver_test(User.find(1), 'email@email.com')
```

or from the user's instance method:

```
UserMailer.deliver_test(self, 'email@email.com')
```

Comment: I already has the mailer's class method inside of the controller as `UserMailer.test.deliver` but after switching to `UserMailer.deliver_test` it works.  What's the difference?

Comment: I believe the `test.deliver` format is specific to Rails 3, whereas `deliver_test` is for Rails 2. Are you on Rails 2?

Comment: Nevermind... They both suddenly started working after a server reboot. :P